# Поиск в больших файлах csv

Tags: java, android

Хочу создать приложение поиска информации о авто и его владельце по автомобильном номере. В публичном доступе есть файлы реестра с 2013 года в формате csv в которых и нужно проводить поиск.
Они тут [Ссылка](https://data.gov.ua/dataset/06779371-308f-42d7-895e-5a39833375f0) .
Так вот очень важный вопрос где держать эти файлы так как они очень большие каждый 500+ МБ. В ресурсах приложения не вариант ведь? Думаю в firebase storage..но не знаю как реализовать поиск в этих файлах. Пользователь вводит только номер автомобиля после чего нужно как то найти этот номер в файлах csv и вывести пользователю всю информацию которая есть. 
Помогите разобраться в данной теме буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Поищите уроки про то как писать backend для android-приложения. Там уже станет яснее, как и на чем строить базу данных. Еще, полагаю, что должно быть ~500 МБ, а не ГБ

Answer (score 4):

Искать по csv у вас так просто не получится. Для этого нужно будет их парсить, в памяти все держать не получится, поэтому придется искать прямо по файлу. Даже если поиск будет осуществляться достаточно редко, боюсь что время все равно он будет занимать приличное.

Я думаю вам нужно просто заимпортировать CSV в какую либо БД (например: [import-csv-file-mysql-table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)). После чего уже работать с БД на сервере через JDBC/Hibernate/Spring Data/что душе угодно. Если данные в CSV не обновляются - это лучший вариант.

Если же данные в CSV обновляются тут уже сложнее. Можно попробовать как в этой теме обсуждается [best-efficient-way-to-search-a-large-csv-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187150/best-efficient-way-to-search-a-large-csv-in-java). Но это уже отдельная тема.

И да, от сервера вы не убежите конечно, мало кто захочет устанавливать приложение весом в несколько гигабайт, да и поиск будет не быстрый.
Можно попробовать обойтись и без сервера, например импортировать данные в какую нибудь Cloud базу данных. Например [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) или [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/). Но эту тему нужно изучать, права доступа настроить обязательно. В общем тоже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Данные не обновляются. Спасибо за совет. Хотелось бы конечно firebase использовать. Буду изучать дальше